# Nested properties spring jpa and operator

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Hi Id like to Query creation from method names like this:

```
public List<TransU> findByTrans_udo_jej_xAndTrans_udo_jej_y(Double x,Double y, Pageable pageable);
```

change into sth like:

```
public List<TransU> findBy[Trans_udo_jej]xAndY(Double x,Double y, Pageable pageable);
```

where both x and y are a part of jej, similar to the first example.
Is it possible? Thank you for help